# Any Known issues upgrading to Windows 8 with Dualboot OS

Tags: windows-8

With Ubuntu 11 installed alongside windows 7, are there any known issues currently - 
while upgrading 7 to 8?

Even minor changes on 7 seemed to disturb the GRUB. Would it be wise to proceed?

Any possible precautions to be considered before upgrading?

Comment: Just disable `Secure Boot`

Comment: Installing Windows always overwrites the bootloader, so you have to be prepared to overwrite it back again.

Comment: Thanks pjc50, and is there no other way to bypass that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you upgrade:

1. Make sure that you a backup of all your important data.
2. Make a bootable USB flash drive to install Windows 8.
3. Make another bootable USB flash drive which you can use to boot into a live Linux distro and install the GRUB bootloader again if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks Root, but I'm just reading other comments about Bootloader getting overwritten. Could you suggest anything to avoid that?

Comment: No Root, I'm not.